# How do you hyphenate compounds that already have hyphens?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

For example, if something happened in the pre-Christian era, is it a

- pre-Christian-era event, or
- pre-Christian era event

To give another example -- we say "low-sodium diets", but would you say that a menu is "low-sodium-based"? It feels over-hyphenated.

Answer (score 0):

What some authors do is use hyphens between two elements that are very closely connected, and dashes between elements that are less closely connected. In this case, since you wrote *pre-Christian era*, it would seem that *pre-* applies to *Christian* only, not to *Christian era*; you could therefore do it like this:

> ?a pre-Christian–era event

But generally people will also use just hyphens:

> ?a pre-Christian-era event

However, adjectives compounded from two nouns are not seldom considered **ugly**. I would never write the above (hence the question marks). And the suffix *-based* is very often superfluous and ugly. General stylistic advice:

**Don't try to put too much information in an adjective; use a clause or post-positional phrase instead, where applicable**.

Your sentences will be the more balanced for it, and easier to read. It is much better to recast the sentence in this case:

> an event from before the Christian era
>
> a diet with little sodium

I think in almost any context, the word *era* doesn't add anything in this phrase:

> a pre-Christian event

A single hyphen would be wrong here (hence the asterisk):

> *a pre-Christian era event

This is wrong, because the adjectival phrases modify the head noun (*event*) in order, going from right to left:

> an event
>
> *an era event
>
> *a pre-Christian [era event]

This is clearly not the intended meaning.